# How to write a simple eclipse plugin that would do code hinting based on @import file

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellisense

I have a css file `overrideme.css` that has some styles

```
.style1{ }
.some{ }
...
.other{ }
.style15{ }
```

In another css file `final.css`, I first do an import of the original file, then try to over write some of the styles

```
@import "overrideme.css";
.style12{ }
```

How can I get Eclipse to give me code hints with the names of these styles when I start to type something that starts with `.`? For example If I type `.st` it would give me `style1` and `style15`. I know very little about extending eclipse itself, but I'm guessing it needs some sort of a plugin which would probably be written in Java which I know very little about. Is it a huge hack to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing simple about what you are trying to do. If you don't already know Java, you will need to learn that first. Then learn Eclipse plugin development. Then start looking at extending an existing .css editor or writing one on your own, perhaps using a framework like Xtext.

Have you looked at existing .css plugins? I would take a look at Eclipse IDE for Java EE development first. If you don't find a satisfactory editor in that distribution, search for CSS on Eclipse marketplace. The marketplace is integrated into Eclipse itself in recent versions of Eclipse. Look under the help menu.